Token for membership fee to be taken by Direct Debit at future date
We need to send an annual scheduled reminder, well in advance of Membership Expiration Date, including the fee to be taken by Direct Debit (autorenewal). The price set for membership fees is updated annually, so we cannot use a token for the previous year's contribution. There are three price points for each of six Membership Types.
Is there a straightforward way to create a Token for the Scheduled Reminder which quotes the relevant amount to be taken on renewal?

Do members have no option as to which price they opt for?

Members have already opted for their price point when they set up the membership, and set up a Direct Debit to renew at the same price point. The purpose of the reminder is to prompt them to consider whether they want to change before the payment is taken.
